# Is pthread_join() a critical function?

Tags: linux, operating-system, posix

According to POSIX, a Thread ID can be reused if the original bearer thread finished. Therefore, would one need to use a mutex or semaphore when calling `pthread_join()`? Because, it could happen that the target thread, which one wants to join, already terminated and another thread with the same thread ID was created, before calling `pthread_join()` in the original thread. This would make the original thread believe that the target thread has not finished, although this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find this works much the same way as processes in UNIX. A joinable thread is not considered *truly* finished until something has actually joined it.

This is similar to the UNIX processes in that, even though they've technically exited, enough status information (including the PID, which cannot be re-used yet) hangs around until another process does a `wait` on it. Only after that point does the PID become available for re-use. This kind of process is called a zombie, since it's dead but not dead.

This is supported by the [pthread_join documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) which states:

> Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this, since each zombie thread consumes some system resources, and when enough zombie threads have accumulated, it will no longer be possible to create new threads (or processes).

and [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), which states:

> Only when a terminated joinable thread has been joined are the last of its resources released back to the system.

Comment: Ok, and is the main thread joinable? If so who joins it to be considered truly finished? Same question with processes. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Jonathan, I believe all threads (including the main one) are meant to be peers in that any thread can join with any other. The main thread is special in that exiting will cause all threads to terminate.